# Fill dataset from another dataset

Tags: c#, dataset, records

I'm trying to store un saved records based on query in dataset to show it in grid view to the user with no luck, How can I save them in dataset using the following code ?

```
 for (int i = 1; i < recs.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        validateQuery = "SELECT .... "
                        conn.Open();
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(validateQuery, conn);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds, "candRecs");
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt = ds.Tables[0];
                        int RowsCount = dt.Rows.Count;

                        if (RowsCount == 0)
                        {
                            //conn.Open();
                            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAND_CARD_NO", recs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
                            ....

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            x++;                                
                            //What I should to write here to store the records in Dataset ?? 
                        }

                        ...
```

Comment: Erm. All you should have to do is call ApplyChanges on the original dataset. it will try to do it for you.

Comment: iterate in source dataset and Get DataRow from that , check conditions , if all conditions is true Add new row in target dataset and transport source to target (fields that you need).